# Как в строчном выражении PHP поменять регистр

Tags: php

```
$str = "ПОМЕНЯТЬ";
```

Как сделать чтобы первая буква осталась заглавной, а остальные сделать строчными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 вариант

```
$str = mb_convert_case("ПОМЕНЯТЬ", MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

2 вариант

```
$str = 'ПОМЕНЯТЬ';

function ucfirst_utf8($str)
{
    return mb_substr(mb_strtoupper($str, 'utf-8'), 0, 1, 'utf-8') . 
    mb_substr(mb_strtolower($str, 'utf-8'), 1, mb_strlen($str)-1, 'utf-8');
}
$str = ucfirst_utf8($str);
```

Comment: Еще вариант: `$str = ucfirst(strtolower("ПОМЕНЯТЬ"));`

Comment: Полезную информацию, вроде этой, лучше добавлять в ответ, а не в комментарии.. Комментарии - эфемерны.

Comment: А можно вместо слова "ПОМЕНЯТЬ" писать $str? так можно?

Comment: `$str = "ПОМЕНЯТЬ";
$str = ucfirst(strtolower($str));`

Comment: `strtolower` и `ucfirst` не работают с utf-8.

Comment: @u_mulder Поправил